# Do all elements in a bucket of an unordered_map have the same hash?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Are all keys in a std::unordered_map guaranteed to have the same hash?
Or can keys with different hashes reside within the same bucket?

Does being in the same bucket imply having the same hash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does being in the same bucket imply having the same hash?

No.

A hash code is a 32-bit or 64-bit number, so could take a vast number of values, but an unordered container doesn't have billions of buckets. It will have N buckets and map the billions of possible codes to one of those N buckets.

Typically it will use the modulus operator (`%`) to reduce the hash code to a smaller value which is used as an index into an array of buckets.

So if there are 13 buckets then every element in a bucket will have the same hash code modulo 13, but not necessarily the same hash code.

The [load_factor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/load_factor) and [max_load_factor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/max_load_factor) members can be used to query and control the "load factor" which describes the average number of elements per bucket. A higher load factor means that elements with different hash codes are more likely to end up in the same bucket (because there are fewer buckets that the `hash%N` values are distributed across).

Comment: By changing `max_load_factor` I was able to reproduce the case of different hashes within the same bucket - thereby verifying your answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not guaranteed anywhere.

**Unordered_map** has function **bucket_size**, which returns the number of elements in specific bucket:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/bucket_size/

This function can return value greater than one, it means that different elements can go to same bucket.

Comment: When that functions returns a value greater than one it can also mean that multiple unequal keys have the same hash. It doesn't have to mean that these values will have a different hash.